# Quartz job from quartz-job.xml run while scheduler start

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am having quartz job to run which is configured from quartz-config.xml which is expected to run every after 5 seconds. Job do run fine but problem is when I run main program which starts scheduler sometimes program runs job immediately after starting scheduler and sometimes after gap of pre defined interval i.e 5 second.

```
<cron-expression>*/5 * * * * ?</cron-expression>
```

How can I make it to run after interval I said after starting the scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

You could delay the start of the scheduler ( http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.5/org/quartz/Scheduler.html#startDelayed(int) )

HIH

Comment: But then each time I change the rate of trigger I would have to change the start time accordingly. Not that elegant :(

Comment: My mistake, I misunderstood. You should use this trigger instead of the cron trigger: http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.5/org/quartz/impl/triggers/DailyTimeIntervalTriggerImpl.html